# How to replace NA's in a raster object

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I need to replace the `NA`'s in the raster object (`r`) from the example below.

```
library(raster)
filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(filename)
```

I also tried to remove these these (and place the result in a `data.frame`), but to no avail.

```
dfr <- as.data.frame(r, na.rm=T)
summary(dfr)
# test       
# Min.   : 128.4  
# 1st Qu.: 293.2  
# Median : 371.4  
# Mean   : 423.2  
# 3rd Qu.: 499.8  
# Max.   :1805.8  
# NA's   :6097
```

Comment: Yes, `summary(as.data.frame(r, na.omit=T))` says that there are 6097 `NA`'s.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. +1 for [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: As you can see in the answer, `na.omit` is a function not an argument of `as.data.frame`.

Comment: I saw that, @seancarmody, thanks!

Comment: Try SpatialPixelsDataFrame for sparse grids without the NAs, but this is pretty open ended, what do you really need?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes sense to remove `NA` values from a `raster` object, but you can easily replace it.

For example:

```
oldpar <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
plot(r)
r[is.na(r)] <- 250
plot(r)
par(oldpar)
```

[image]

---

If you really want to, you can extract the raster values into a vector and then remove the `NA` values. (Although, since you lose the spatial information, I can't see how this can be helpful.)

```
r <- raster(filename)

r <- values(r)
head(r)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA

head(na.omit(r))
[1] 633.686 712.545 654.162 604.442 857.256 755.506
```

Answer (score 31):

Here are three ways in which you can do this with `terra`

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
x <- classify(r, cbind(NA, -99))
y <- subst(r, NA, -99)
z <- ifel(is.na(r), -99, r)
```

With `raster`, the best (memory safe approach that also works for large files) is to use reclassify:

```
library(raster)
filename <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(filename)
rna <- reclassify(r, cbind(NA, 250))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for NaN (i.e. reclassify(r, cbind(NaN, NA)))

Comment: Using the "in-place" function set.values, we can also write: set.values(r, which(is.na(values(r))), -99), which is perhaps the fastest way to substitute values in a terra raster.

Comment: That may be, but using `values` is not memory safe, so I won't recommend it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not memory-safe"? Are you talking about the fact that all the other rasters pointing to the modified raster are also modified? Or is there another danger?

Comment: `values` attempts to read all raster cell values into memory. That may not be possible.